# Automatically find identical photos from two different libraries and replace the original metadata

Tags: software-recommendation

Here is my problem, I mirrored my entire photo library over to a new system, and then I organised them there and renamed some of the photo file names too. I must have made a mistake somewhere along the line, resulting in all of the photos to have their 'date modified' metadata reset to the current date.

This really stuffed up my photo library as most of my photos don't have any 'date taken' metadata, and my photo library software (Plex / [PhotoPrism](https://photoprism.app/)) was relying on the `'date modified'` field in order to organise and date my photos. I'm not sure what caused this to happen, the only thing I recall doing was running `chmod` commands on the library directory to change the permission of the photos, however that should not have modified the `'date modified'` field, I think...

Anyway, what I need is some sort of program or script that will go through each photo/video in library A *(original library)* and find its corresponding photo from library B *(new library)* and then replace the date modified field from library B with library A. I'm guessing the script would have to take a hash value of each photo and compare using that since the file names/directories are different now.

Has anyone else had an issue similar to this, and does this solution sound like something that is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Ask in [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (since you use `chmod` you have a Unix shell). What you want to do is identify the source file (by comparing hashes) and then use it with `touch -r $sourceFile $badDateFile`. The fact that the contents are photos is irrelevant. Perhaps state your OS when asking the question (OSX or Linux...).

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have just posted in Superuser, my bad.